# SQL MATCH not Matching correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, and i have joined them together, which works fine, it pulls the information.  One of the tables as an array within a column, on every row like:

```
["Pets","Schools","Shops"]
```

I need, while selecting, the query to pull out when a MATCH AGAINST a var.  Here is my code:

```
$searchRefine = '';
foreach( $refineAmen as  $key => $val) {
    $searchRefine = $searchRefine . " MATCH(pa.Property_Amenities) AGAINST ('".$val."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR ";
}
```

The above takes each var from the array from the row / column, and adds it to a sub-query string.

```
$searchRefine = substr($searchRefine, 0, -3);
```

The above takes out the last 3 (or the word 'OR') at the end as its not needed

```
$detail = "SELECT  p.*, pi.*, pa.*  FROM  tbl_property p LEFT join tbl_property_images pi on p.Property_Id = pi.Property_Id LEFT join tbl_property_amenities pa on pi.Property_Id = pa.Property_Id WHERE (p.Property_Postcode='" . $_POST['cust_id'] . "' OR p.Property_City Like '%" . $_POST['cust_id'] . "%') AND ( " . $searchRefine. " ) GROUP BY pi.Property_Id";
```

The above takes the sub strings and adds it to the final for firing.  I do not get any errors.

The issue is, it does not pull the records with any of these key works within the row, just One. I have tried a number of combinations of AND or OR, so the query understands.  But still no luck.  Any someone look at this, and see if they can see what I have done wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your database structure instead of storing multiple values in one column. This way you would not have to compute a sub-query string for fulltext search with `MATCH...AGAINST`.
Can you show your database structure?

Beware of SQL injection. Once your query is working you should alter it to escape client data oder use prepared statements.

Comment: My Rep was too low for a normal comment.

Comment: The structure was inherited, but you are saying its best to have lots of records, rather than less records with a json inside of it.  I do not see that as an advantage when it comes to size, but if thats whats recommended, ill change it :)

Comment: I don't think size should be your main concern here. But database size would decrease anyway with normalization.
Main advantages would be that writing (and reading) queries gets easier and queries execute faster.
I am not sure about the goal of your query. Could you provide an example for the tables und which values you want to find?